# Sessions are not supported by the MongoDB cluster (and mongo instance is replica set)

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am running a mongo replica set (one instant) on a docker container for testing.

Getting the above mentioned error while using client "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-reactivestreams:1.10.0"

the container starts in gradle build using bmuschko lib with the below task:

```
task createMongoContainer(type: DockerCreateContainer) {
    targetImageId "mongo:latest"
    containerName = mongoLatest
    hostConfig.autoRemove = true
    hostConfig.portBindings = ["26016:27017"]

    cmd = ["--replSet", "rs0"]

    }
```